# What is this bivariate distribution called and how to make it posterior?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, joint-distribution, bivariate

I am trying to make this bivariate density function as posterior

```
 f(x,y) = k x^2 exp( - x y^2 - y^2 + 2y - 4x)
```

and try jags instead of implementing in R as in the link below.

https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/gibbs-sampler-in-various-languages-revisited/

the problem is it doesn't look like any standard distribution offered by BUGS.

My initial plan was to make likelihood as unif(0,1) or something and

one observed variable is 1/2 or something and let f(x,y) be f(x)*f(y)

(f(x) and f(y) be priors) or let f(x,y) be multivariate priors

Any idea on what the distribution is called and how to make it posterior?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand how you came with the density.

Answer (score 4):

This is a joint density: from $$f(x,y) \propto x^2 \exp\left( - x y^2 - y^2 + 2y - 4x\right)$$you can derive that
\begin{align*}f(y|x)&\propto\exp\left( - x y^2 - y^2 + 2y\right)\\
&\propto\exp\left(-(1+x)[y^2-2y/(1+x)]\right)\\
&\propto\exp\left(-(1+x)[y-1/(1+x)]^2\right)\end{align*}
Therefore you can deduce that$$Y|X=x\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{1+x},\frac{1}{2(1+x)}\right)$$
The marginal distribution of $X$ is given by
\begin{align*}f(x) &\propto x^2\exp\{-4x\}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(1+x)y^2+2y}\,\text{d}y\\
&\propto x^2\exp\{-4x\}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(1+x)[y-1/(1+x)]^2+1/(1+x)}\,\text{d}y\\
&\propto x^2\exp\{-4x+1/(1+x)\}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}\end{align*}
which does not look like a standard distribution.

However, the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is also standard:
\begin{align*}f(x|y) &\propto x^2\exp\{-4x -xy^2\}\\
&\propto x^{3-1} \exp\{-(4+y^2)x\}\\\end{align*}which implies that
$$X|Y=y\sim Ga(3,(4+y^2))$$
This implies you can use Gibbs sampling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think you misunderstood the question. My whole purpose was to implement it via jags. So I have to make f(x,y) somehow posterior distribution like f(x,y | X). here X is data. f(x,y|X)=f(X|x,y)p(x,y)/f(X). given f(X) is constant, I need to find a way to represent f(x,y|X) = f(X|x,y)p(x,y)...p(x,y) : priors for x,y.  X can be any constants satisfying f(x,y |X)=f(x,y)

Comment: Sorry, your comment makes no sense...

Comment: okay.. let f(x,y) be itself and think of some model with prior g(x,y) and likelihood L(X|x,y). BUGS samples from posterior g(x,y|X) right? in doing so  BUGS(JAGS) samples like g(x|y,X) and (y|x,X). So I want to sample from f(x,y) via JAGS(BUGS). How would you do that?